# Installing .deb package twice calls postrm

Tags: linux, package-management, dpkg, deb

I am toubleshooting a basic .deb package built from the include script below, specifically its operation if it is installed twice via `dpkg -i <package-name>`.  I found that the `postrm` script is always called.

The [official maintainer scripts](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) do not show a case for the same package being installed twice.  When I install the following script twice, it will execute the `postrm` (or `prerm` if I configure the package with one) in between the `preisnt` and `postinst`.

This flow doesn't seem to make sense to me since why would installing again follow the flow:

1. preinst
2. prerm
3. postrm
4. postinst

If anything from rm would be executed I assume it would be the following:

1. prerm
2. postrm
3. preinst
4. postinst

The `preinst` returns an `exit code 0` even the second time its executed, so that would not trigger the `prerm` or `postrm`.

My question is: Is there a way to avoid calling `prerm` and `postrm` under these circumstances?  Is there a way to determine how `prerm` or `postrm` was called from within the script itself? (since it was not called during a normal install).

Here Is the script in case it is useful to see:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Command line parameters
USERNAME="$1"
PUBKEY_FILE="$2"
TEMP_DIR="$3"
OUTPUT_PATH=$4
MAINTAINER_EMAIL="$5"

# Verify required args
if [ -z "${USERNAME}" ] || [ -z "${PUBKEY_FILE}" ] || [ -z "${TEMP_DIR}" ] || [ -z "${OUTPUT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 USERNAME PUBKEY_FILE TEMP_DIR OUTPUT_PATH" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Ensure maintainer email
if [ -z "${MAINTAINER_EMAIL}" ]
then
  MAINTAINER_HOSTNAME="$(hostname)"
  if [ -z "$HOSTNAME" ]
  then
    MAINTAINER_HOSTNAME="localhost"
  fi
  MAINTAINER_EMAIL="admin@${MAINTAINER_HOSTNAME}"
fi

# Constants
# Package data
PACKAGE_NAME="xyz-lsc-target-${USERNAME}"
PACKAGE_VERSION="0.5-1"
PACKAGE_NAME_VERSION="${PACKAGE_NAME}_${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
MAINTAINER="Maintainer Name  <${MAINTAINER_EMAIL}>"
PACKAGE_DATE=$(date "+%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
# Used for identifying username entry in /etc/passwd
USER_COMMENT="XYZ Local Security Checks"
USER_COMMENT_GREP="XYZ\\ Local\\ Security\\ Checks"

# Paths
PACKAGE_BASE_DIR="${TEMP_DIR}/${PACKAGE_NAME_VERSION}"

# Data paths
DATA_DIR="${PACKAGE_BASE_DIR}"
HOME_SUBDIR="home/${USERNAME}"
HOME_DATA_DIR="${DATA_DIR}/${HOME_SUBDIR}"
SSH_DATA_DIR="${HOME_DATA_DIR}/.ssh"
DOC_SUBDIR="usr/share/doc/${PACKAGE_NAME}"
DOC_DATA_DIR="${DATA_DIR}/${DOC_SUBDIR}"

# Control file path
CONTROL_DIR="${PACKAGE_BASE_DIR}/DEBIAN"

#
# Test dependencies
#
if [ -z "$(which dpkg)" ]
then
  echo "dpkg not found" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$(which fakeroot)" ]
then
  echo "fakeroot not found" >&2
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$(which md5sum)" ]
then
  echo "md5sum not found" >&2
  exit 1
fi


#
# Create data files
#

# Create .ssh directory
mkdir -p "${SSH_DATA_DIR}"

# Copy public key
AUTH_KEYS_FILE="${SSH_DATA_DIR}/authorized_keys"
cp "${PUBKEY_FILE}" "${AUTH_KEYS_FILE}"

# Create doc directory
mkdir -p "${DOC_DATA_DIR}"

# Create Changelog
cd "${DOC_DATA_DIR}"
CHANGELOG_FILE="${DOC_DATA_DIR}/changelog.Debian"
{
  echo "${PACKAGE_NAME} (${PACKAGE_VERSION}) experimental; urgency=low"
  echo ""
  echo "  * Automatically generated local security check credential package"
  echo "  "
  echo ""
  echo " -- ${MAINTAINER}  ${PACKAGE_DATE}"
} > "${CHANGELOG_FILE}"

# Compress Changelog
gzip -f --best "${CHANGELOG_FILE}"
CHANGELOG_FILE="${CHANGELOG_FILE}.gz"

# Create Copyright info
COPYRIGHT_FILE="${DOC_DATA_DIR}/copyright"
{
  echo "Format: https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/"
  echo ""
  echo "Files: *"
  echo "Copyright: 2018-2020 Greenbone AG"
  echo "License: GPL-2+ (/usr/share/common-licenses/GPL-2)"
} > "${COPYRIGHT_FILE}"

# Create data archive
cd "${DATA_DIR}"
tar -C "${DATA_DIR}" -z -cf "../data.tar.gz" "${HOME_SUBDIR}" "${DOC_SUBDIR}"


#
# Create control files
#

# Create directory
mkdir -p "${CONTROL_DIR}"
chmod "0755" "${CONTROL_DIR}"

# Create "control" file
CONTROL_FILE="${CONTROL_DIR}/control"
{
  echo "Package: ${PACKAGE_NAME}"
  echo "Version: ${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
  echo "Maintainer: ${MAINTAINER}"
  echo "Priority: optional"
  echo "Architecture: all"
  echo "Description: XYZ local security check preparation"
  echo " This package prepares a system for XYZ local security checks."
  echo " A user is created with a specific SSH authorized key."
  echo " The corresponding private key is located at the respective"
  echo " XYZ installation."
} > "${CONTROL_FILE}"

# Create "preinst" file run before installation
PREINST_FILE="${CONTROL_DIR}/preinst"
touch "${PREINST_FILE}"
chmod "0755" "${PREINST_FILE}"
{
  echo "#!/bin/sh"
  echo "# Delete XYZ Local Security Checks by username and comment"
  echo "grep \"${USERNAME}.*${USER_COMMENT_GREP}\" /etc/passwd && userdel -fr ${USERNAME}"
  echo "# XYZ Local Security Checks user and create home directory"
  echo "useradd -c \"${USER_COMMENT}\" -d /home/${USERNAME} -m -s /bin/bash ${USERNAME}"
  echo "# Return exit status 0 to prevent instrm from being triggered"
  echo "# https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html"
  echo "exit 0"
} > "${PREINST_FILE}"

# Create "postinst" file run after installation
POSTINST_FILE="${CONTROL_DIR}/postinst"
touch "${POSTINST_FILE}"
chmod "0755" "${POSTINST_FILE}"
{
  echo "#!/bin/sh"
  echo "# Change file permissions"
  echo "chown -R ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} /home/${USERNAME}"
  echo "chmod 500 /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh"
  echo "chmod 400 /home/${USERNAME}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  echo "exit 0"
} > "${POSTINST_FILE}"

# Create "postinst" file run after removal or on error
POSTRM_FILE="${CONTROL_DIR}/prerm"
touch "${POSTRM_FILE}"
chmod "0755" "${POSTRM_FILE}"
{
  echo "#!/bin/sh"
  echo "echo 'prerm file called!!'"
  echo "# Remove user only if it was created by this package."
  echo "# The debian package will run the postun script in case of errors"
  echo "# (e.g. user already existed)."
  echo "# Delete the user only if /etc/passwd lists content that suggests"
  echo "# that the user was created by this package."
  # echo "set -e  # abort on errors"
  echo "grep \"${USERNAME}.*${USER_COMMENT_GREP}\" /etc/passwd && userdel -fr ${USERNAME}"
} > "${POSTRM_FILE}"

# Calculate md5 checksums
MD5SUMS_FILE="${CONTROL_DIR}/md5sums"
cd "${DATA_DIR}"
{
  md5sum "${HOME_SUBDIR}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
  md5sum "${DOC_SUBDIR}/changelog.Debian.gz"
  md5sum "${DOC_SUBDIR}/copyright"
} > "${MD5SUMS_FILE}"

#
# Build package
#

# Combine into .deb file
cd "${TEMP_DIR}"
fakeroot -- dpkg --build "${PACKAGE_NAME_VERSION}" "${OUTPUT_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that instead of trying to distinguish initial installations, upgrades and repeat installations, you might want to change your `postrm` so that it only removes the user on `purge`. That way, the user remains during upgrades etc. and is only removed if you remove the package with `apt purge` or `dpkg --purge` (or equivalent).

To do this, check `postrm`’s first argument; if it’s `purge`, remove the user, otherwise do nothing. You might also want to change your `preinst` so that it doesn’t remove an existing user and only creates the user if it doesn’t already exist.

Comment: Although this solution seems like a good one at first, in this case, I do want the package to remove the user if errors were created during the install process. So, I would have to test that to determine if the process from a failed `preinst` would pass the `purge` argument.  If it does then this would work, thanks!

Comment: Given that you found [the maintainer script flowcharts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-flowcharts.html), I thought you would have noticed that there are specific error-handling flows. *That’s* how you should handle errors.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with that.  However, looking through the Debian documentation, especially the [Chapter 2] (https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html) I don't see a coherent description of the arguments used to call each script.  Are you able to provide any hints as to (1) Where a comprehensive description of the process flow can be found and (2) guide to terminology related to the command arguments.  The diagram helpful, but a bit lacking.

Comment: While I could try echoing them to debug, it's not such a reliable method to account for what I may encounter and end up causing more problems by implementing a half-baked solution.

Comment: They’re [documented in Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html).

Comment: Thanks kindly I didn't expect a separate policy documentation in addition to the reference manual.  I kinda thought it would be in the reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the procedure that is being used to call the `prerm` or `postrm` from the first argument `$1`. In the case of installing the same version, the `upgrade` procedure will be used.

The diagram show the process flow for `upgrade`.

[image]

So, adding a conditional statement to the `prerm` or `postrm` file such as the one below will not execute the package removal process when executing it twice, but will also not execute it it upgrading the package.

```
if [ $1 != "upgrade" ]; then
  # do regular remove process
fi
```

Comment: The problem with the only solution I can find is that it doesn't distinguish between re-install the same package and upgrading.